# How to automatically redirect my jsp page to another jsp page?

Tags: java

I am doing a project of intrusion detection.In that If a user takes a long time in one jsp page, then the jsp page should automatically redirect to another jsp or html ? How can I do this ? Please help guys ..

Comment: it's the page flow fixed? (eg. a.jsp --> b.jsp --> c.jsp) and the routing between jsp performet through some sort of centralized "controller/servlet" ? Is the client-side approach (e.g. javascript), an option ?

Comment: If your 2nd jsp has some object models which it is taking from the backend, then you will get a Binding result exception. Don't forget that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add a [html meta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh) tag to the jsp page like this:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5; url=http://example.com/">
```

Comment: Deleted my answer - didn't know you could do this without JavaScript, nice solution :-)

Comment: @Nick we all are learning whole life ;) (somebody say: and die stupid) Thank for Your "elastycism" (my speller underscore this word, i don't know how in english)

Answer (score 1):

For me seems better than JS

```
 <head>
    <META http-equiv="refresh" content="5;URL=http://bla bala/xxx">
   </head>
```

URL can be local as usual